# Receiving Data Header over TCP IP

Tags: vba, sockets, tcp, header, client

I made a program to receive data from a 2D scanner, but when I use the `GetData` method, it returns me a data that I do not know what part of the header is. So I created a User Define Type according to the header reported in the scanner manual but I can not get the packages according to each type. Below is the code I made in `VBA` with the `Winsock` control. Also a header printout reported in the scanner manual.

```
 Private WithEvents tcpClient As Winsock
    Public Event DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Private Type packet_Header   
        magic As Integer
        packet_type As Integer
        packet_size As Integer
        header_size As Integer
        scan_number As Integer
        packet_number As Integer
        timestamp_raw As Date
        timestamp_sync As Date
        status_flags As Integer
        scan_frequency As Integer
        num_points_scan As Integer
        num_points_packet As Integer
        first_index As Integer
        first_angle As Integer
        iq_input As Integer
        angular_increment As Integer
        iq_overload As Integer
        header_padding As Integer
    End Type
    Private Type scan_point_data
        distance As Integer
    End Type

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set tcpClient = New MSWinsockLib.Winsock
tcpClient.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
tcpClient.Connect "169.254.218.229", "59164"
MsgBox tcpClient.State
'MsgBox tcpClient.SocketHandle
MsgBox tcpClient.BytesReceived
End Sub

Public Sub tcpClient_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Dim teste As packet_Header
tcpClient.GetData teste.magic
MsgBox teste.magic
End Sub
```

Scanner:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the headers as reported in the scanner manual?

Comment: Some of the types don't match the spec: `uint32/int32` should be `As Long`, `ntp64` should be `As Currency` and `uint8[]` should be `As Long`.

Comment: I've made the changes but I'm still getting random data. If you help, there is this code in [GitHub]. The link is this: : https://github.com/StaudtEngineering/LidaRx
I looked but could not figure out how to decode the packages to work the data the way I need it, Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you at least read `41564` in `magic`. It shouldn't be too hard given that the API seems well documented and you also have access at the .Net implementation. Try to read the bytes first in a byte array and then copy it to the defined type.

Comment: was correct. the magic is -23972. I created a loop to find it and then I distribute the others.Thanks a lot for the help.